# Parsing a file into 3 separate arrays

Tags: c++, string, parsing, split

I want to know how to parse a string, such that I store the first number into a double array, the second number into a separate double array, and the remaining string in its own separate array as well; the input has the format:

```cpp
Los Angeles 31.00 40.10
Miami 108.12 20.11
Nashville 44.33 25.99
```

They are separated by a single space, and each city name with the coordinates are separated line by line. I want to just split the string by white space and new lines, but there are cities (like Los Angeles) that have a space in between.  How can I put these all into their respective `string[]` and `double[]` arrays? I can't think of a way to add "Los Angeles" into a string array without it being "Los" and "Angeles"

Comment: What does your code look like so far? And where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Might be a good job for [std::regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to keep adding onto the string while the next token is not a double. Essentially, you would extract the next "string", and test if it's a double. If it is, then you would rollback the stream's position to before reading the last string, and continue parsing doubles. Otherwise, you would keep adding strings.

For a single line, you might be able to do something like this. Note: this assumes that you want to get all words until you hit a double, so if you had two adjacent string fields where the first and or second one could contain spaces, this wouldn't work.

```
ifstream filein("path");

for(int i = 0; filein; i++) //each line of the file
{
    std::string line;
    getline(filein, line); //use getline to safely get the next line

    std::stringstream lineStream(line); //create a stream to extract from

    //assuming cities is the string array, and i is a loopvar
    cities[i] = extractUntilDouble(lineStream);

    //can now get the other properties from lineStream

}
```

where the following functions are defined as

```
std::string extractUntilDouble(const std::istream & filestream)
{
    std::string toReturn="";
    std::string token="";
    
    std::streampos fallbackPosition; //used since we will take one extra chunk 
    //than we should at the end, want the caller to be able to extract that

    do
    {
        toReturn += token;
        fallbackPosition = filestream.tellg(); //save position before extracting
        filestream >> token;
    } while (!isNumeric(token)); //check if this token is a number

    filestream.seekg(filestream); //go back to the last token
    
}

bool isNumeric(const string& str)
{
    return str.find_first_not_of("0123456789.") == std::string::npos;
}
```

This probably isn't the most efficient or elegant way of doing this, but a potential solution. You could also override the global >> string operator to do this, to use that sweet insertion syntax and avoid the extra explicit method call, but that may of course cause unexpected behavior later...